# How can i reshape an array from (280, 280, 3) to (28, 28, 3)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, artificial-intelligence, datashape

Hi i tried to write a code, where i write a number on the screen with pygame and then a neural Network predicts the number i wrote. My problem is that i trained my neural network with image arrays in a (28, 28, 3). So i tried to reshape my (280, 280, 3) array. but when i do so my array is None.
I use Python 3.7

```
string_image = pygame.image.tostring(screen, 'RGB')
temp_surf = pygame.image.fromstring(string_image, (280, 280), 'RGB')
array = pygame.surfarray.array3d(temp_surf)
array = array.resize((28, 28, 3))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to scale a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), then I recommend to use [`pygame.transform.scale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) or [`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale).

For instance:

```py
temp_surf = pygame.image.fromstring(string_image, (280, 280), 'RGB')
scaled_surf = pygame.transform.smoothscale(temp_surf, (28, 28))
array = pygame.surfarray.array3d(scaled_surf)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `pygame` but it looks like `pygame.surfarray.array3d` returns a `numpy`-array.

[How to iterate through a pygame 3d surfarray and change the individual color of the pixels if they're less than a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683482/how-to-iterate-through-a-pygame-3d-surfarray-and-change-the-individual-color-of)

To keep the same number of data points and just change the shape you can use `numpy.reshape`.

```
import numpy as np
c = 28*28*3 # just to start off with right amount of data
a = np.arange(c) # this just creates the initial data you want to format
b = a.reshape((28,28,3)) # this actually reshapes the data
d = b.shape #this just stores the new shape in variable d
print(d) #shows you the new shape
```

To interpolate the data to a new size then there are a number of ways like CV or continuing a `numpy` example.

```
ary = np.resize(b,(18,18,1))
e = ary.shape
print(e)
```

Hope that helps.